# Proceed to each link, find file type and download

Tags: web-scraping, vbscript

I am wondering is there any solution to download files from a website with VBscript?

I know how to download a single file from a website but how can I make it into a loop? Also how can I search a particular page for a certain file extension and download the file(s) if available?

```
For each pdf in website
  xhr.open "GET", pdf.src, False
  xhr.send
  set stream = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
  with stream
    .type = 1
    .Open
    .Write xhr.responsebody
    .SaveToFile "C:\temp\" + CStr(index) + ".pdf", 2
  end with 
  stream.Close
  set stream = nothing
  index = index + 1 
Next
```

Let's say we have a website `https://website.com/productpage/` then there are links that all have the same structure `https://website.com/products/xx-x-xx-x/` so all needed links start with `https://website.com/products/`. There seems to be 33 links of that kind according to source code.

Then after proceeding to some page there are PDF files. Sometimes one, sometimes 3 or 4. However link to the PDF file is something like `https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/xxxx.pdf` where xxxx.pdf can actually be a filename.

Here is what I have managed to get for one file:

```
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/xxxx.pdf", False
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "c:\temp\xxxx.pdf", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

---

**EDIT:**

Should it go like:

1. Get all the needed links
2. Proceed to each link
3. Search for links that are ending with ".pdf"
4. Download files to C:\temp\

Structure of website:

```
https://website.com/productpage/
        https://website.com/products/xx-x/
              https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/xx-xx.pdf
        https://website.com/products/xxxxx-xsx/
              https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/x-xx-x.pdf
              https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/x-x-xx.pdf
              https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/xxx-x.pdf
        https://website.com/products/x-xx-xsx/
              https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/x-xxx.pdf
              https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/x-x-x-x.pdf
        https://website.com/products/xx-x-xsx/
              https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/x-xxxx.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the code to save a link, you can wrap it into a sub for re-use:

```
Sub GetFile(p_sRemoteFile, p_sLocalFile)

    Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    xHttp.open "GET", p_sRemoteFile, False
    xHttp.Send

    With bStrm
        .Type = 1 '//binary
        .open
        .write xHttp.responseBody
        .SaveToFile p_sLocalFile, 2 '//overwrite
    End With

End Sub
```

Then, you can use the InternetExplorer object to get a collection of links in a page:

```
Sub GetPageLinks(p_sURL)
    Dim objIE
    Dim objLinks
    Dim objLink
    Dim iCounter

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate p_sURL

    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
        Wscript.Sleep 100
    Loop

    Set objLinks = objIE.Document.All.Tags("a")
    For iCounter = 1 To objLinks.Length
        Set objLink = objLinks(iCounter - 1)
        With objLink
            If StrComp(Right(.href, 3), "pdf", 1) = 0 Then
                ' Get file
                GetFile .href, "C:\temp\downloads\" & GetFileNameFromURL(.href)
            Else
                ' Process page
                GetPageLinks .href
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Here's a function that extracts the file name from a URL:

```
Function GetFileNameFromURL(p_sURL)
    Dim arrFields

    arrFields = Split(p_sURL, "/")

    GetFileNameFromURL = arrFields(UBound(arrFields))

End Function
```

This function will return `xxxx.pdf` given `https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/xxxx.pdf`.

Comment: This looks like the ready solution, however I am a bit confused. Where my actual link now goes? I also have to make another sub for listing all the 33 links first?

Comment: If you have the links already, you can call `GetPageLinks` for each of them. If you have a top page where all the products are listed, you can just use that link, it will go through all the links on that page and process each product page too.

Comment: Sorry I have created only couple simple VBS files before with some scripts. I have mainly used Excel VBA before. Does it mean that I just drop these codes into a file and then add at the top `GetPageLinks("top level link")` ?

Comment: Ok, now I have it running. The problem is that it is now opening front page in many windows. I guess there should be some splitter for `objIE.Document.All.Tags("a")`. So it will open links only starting with `https://website.com/products/`. And then there search for PDF's

Comment: Yes, it opens every link but you can add extra logic to this code. It is not meant as a finished product but as a guide for what you want to do.